# PHP http error 500, domain is unable to handle this request

Tags: php, html, http, http-status-code-500

I was trying to get image file from user by using HTML form and PHP, all good but when the request is sent to the server the client gets an http 500 Error. I guess this related to some code issues but I couldn't find it. 
PHP storm debugger does not show any errors

my html form:

```html
<form method="POST" action="img.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <textarea style="resize:none" name="data"></textarea>
  <div> <input type="file" name="upfile" id="upfile" /></div>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="encrypt" />
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="decrypt" />
</form>
```

my php code:

```js
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  $file = $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'];
  if (file_exists($file)) {
    $imagesizedata = getimagesize($file);
    if ($imagesizedata === FALSE || !testExtension($_FILES['upfile']['name']) || ($_FILES['upfile']['size'] > 50000)) {
      throw new Exception("The file is not an image Or to big");
    } else {
      $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
      $data = inputValidation($_POST['data']); //example
      $selection = inputValidation($_POST['submit']);
      if ($selection == 'encrypt') { //image
        if ($q = strlen($data) % 3 != 0) {
          $q==1?$data.="--":$data.="-";
        }
        if ($img != false) {
          $j = 0;
          for ($i = 0; $i <= (strlen($data) - 3); $i += 3) {
            $part = substr($data, $i, 3);
            $color = getEncryptedColor($img, $part);
            imagesetpixel($img, $j++, 0, $color);
          }
        }
        //display image//+*+*+*+*+*+*+*
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($img);
      } else if ($selection == 'decrypt') {
        //decrypt from image - remove on release
        $dataDec = decryptAllData($img, strlen($data) / 3);
        echo "".$dataDec;
      }
    }
  } else {
    throw new Exception("The upload is not a file or the file doesn't exist anymore.");
  }
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
}

function inputValidation($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

function decryptAllData($img, $datasize) {
  $decrypted = "";
  for ($i = 0; $i < $datasize; $i++) {
    $decrypted.= decryptDataFromPixel($img, $i, 0);
  }
  return $decrypted;
}

function getEncryptedColor($img, $string) {
  return imagecolorallocate($img, ord($string[0]), ord($string[1]), ord($string[2]));
}

function printImageValues($image, $num) {
  for ($x = 0; $x < $num; $x++) {
    echo "\n".imagecolorat($image, $x, $x);
  }
  echo "--END--";
}

function decryptDataFromPixel($img, $x, $y) {
  $currpixel = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y);
  $colors = imagecolorsforindex($img, $currpixel);
  $str = "".chr($colors["red"]).chr($colors["green"]).chr($colors["blue"]);
  return $str;
}

function testExtension($current_image) {
  $extension = substr(strrchr($current_image, '.'), 1);
  if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "gif") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "bmp")) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: 500 can mean any error, can you switch show error on? For example `$data. = "--" : $data. = "-";` is not good php code

Comment: @IvanBolnikh that was my fault, the JS pretty print messed those up

Comment: You may want to change `$q==1?$data.="--":$data.="-";` to `$data .=  ( $q == 1 ) ? "--": "-";`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the spaces in ternary operator

```
$q == 1 ? $data.= "--" : $data.= "-";
```

or

```
$data.= ($q == 1 ? "--" : "-");
```

Comment: That was a formatting issue. Not in the original The original was `$q==1?$data.="--":$data.="-";`